# FLASH urlrequest encoding issue - not getting UTF8 when sent from IE

Tags: flash, encoding

But it does work when I use chrome or FF. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to add more information about what the problem is, but out of curiousity, in your loader do you make a call like this (right before you load the url request)?
    loader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;